# Query MSQL for winners, starting at xth place using SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, limit, sql-order-by

In my MySQL table `Winners`, I have a list of people who have won.

What I'd like to do is select a list of the names of 10 winners. So what I have right now is this:

```
SELECT name FROM Winners ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10
```

This returns the first 10 winners which is great.

But how can I make it (for example) return 10 winners, but starting at 20th place? Right now all I can think of is removing the LIMIT and programatically pulling out the 10 winners I want. But I'm sure there's an easier way.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  name
FROM    Winners
ORDER BY
        points DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

or just

```
SELECT  name
FROM    Winners
ORDER BY
        points DESC
LIMIT 20, 10
```

Comment: Thanks; nice and simple :) - Edit: I like that second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM Winners ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 20, 10
```